# MongoDB is using too much memory

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos

I'm working with MongoDB on a 32bits CentOS VPS with 1GB of internal memory.
It works fine most of the time, but every now and then it's memory usage spikes and crashes my server.

Is there a way to prevent this, for example, by limiting the memory and CPU that MongoDB daemon uses?

I was thinking of running the Mongo daemon with `ionice` and giving it a low priority, but I'm not sure if that would work.

Any help or pointers are welcome!

Comment: Wow, interesting. You should probably post this on the mongoDB mailing list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not currently possible to limit amount of memory. MongoDB uses [memory-mapped file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) mechanism to access data files. Therefore, amount of used memory is governed by the system. The more data you touch, the more RAM you need.

Comment: As a consequence of using memory-mapped files, [MongoDB on 32-bit systems will be limited to about 2 gigabytes of data](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations). You may want to consider using a 64-bit machine for your database.

Comment: @dcrosta: true, forgot to mention that.

Comment: SergioTulentsev, dcrosta, thanks for the tips! it's a test enviroment with limited budget but production will be on 64bits system much heavier then this one so I guess the problem will be solved once i transfer the project (as longs as I add more hardware when needed)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're also running everything else on that same server?

Really, the best way to run mongo is to put it on its own server, where things like apache, mysql, etc. won't jump up and interfere with the RAM it wants to use. I had the same problem myself--the server would go into swap and choke itself every once in a while, with heavy use.

You'd probably be better off with two 512MB servers which is hopefully comparable in price (one running mongo, and one running the rest). I also thought about trying to run a VM with mongo on it within the VPS, but that fell into the "too much effort" category, for me.

And yeah, as dcrosta says, use 64-bit, unless you want to limit your data size to under 2GB (and why would you want to do that?)

Comment: Hey Wes, thanks for that. The server is for development so no budget for complicated setups unfortunatily but the production enviroment will be much heavier so as far is i read issues should then be fixed once on a 64bit system!

Answer (score 1):

I did have similar problems, when I was using lots of map/reduce where the memory leaks and crashes were often. I don't use map/reduce anymore and there have been no memory leaks / crashes for many months now.